# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 30, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(30, 224, 224, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am working of video classification using InceptionV3 and GRU. My dataset is labeled into two classes. I have extracted the frames from video(Sequnece_length=30) and stored in frames_list list which contains video index, frame index, height, weight and channel. I have converted in 4D numpy array:

```
four_dim_list = [frame for video in frames_list for frame in video]
frame_list = np.array(four_dim_list)
```

Length of frame_list is 3660 (from 122 video samples * 30 frames) and also the label_list contains 3660 labels(labels per frame).

To train that I have used a pretrained model InceptionV3 and used two stacked GRU layer (16 unit and 8 unit). The implementation is below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import InceptionV3
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GRU, Dense, TimeDistributed, Masking, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling3D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling3D, MaxPooling2D

num_frames=30
sample=122
BATCH_SIZE=30
EPOCHS = 5
IMG_SIZE = 224

# Preprocess frames
preprocessed_frames = preprocess_input(frame_list)

# InceptionV3 model with pretrained weights
inception_model = tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3))

# GRU model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

# TimeDistributed layer with the InceptionV3-based feature extractor
model.add(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(inception_model, input_shape=(num_frames, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0.0))
num_elements = 5 * 5 * 2048
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((num_frames, num_elements)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GRU(units=16, return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GRU(units=8))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()


#Model Training
model.fit(preprocessed_frames, label_list, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS)
```

While running the code I am getting error in the input layer dimension incompatibility.

Here is the model summary and error:

```
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/keras-applications/inception_v3/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5
87910968/87910968 [==============================] - 0s 0us/step
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 time_distributed (TimeDist  (None, 30, 5, 5, 2048)    21802784  
 ributed)                                                        
                                                                 
 masking (Masking)           (None, 30, 5, 5, 2048)    0         
                                                                 
 reshape (Reshape)           (None, 30, 51200)         0         
                                                                 
 gru (GRU)                   (None, 30, 16)            2458464   
                                                                 
 gru_1 (GRU)                 (None, 8)                 624       
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 8)                 0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 8)                 72        
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 9         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 24261953 (92.55 MB)
Trainable params: 24227521 (92.42 MB)
Non-trainable params: 34432 (134.50 KB)
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-e2802569fee1> in <cell line: 38>()
     36 
     37 #Train the model
---> 38 model.fit(preprocessed_frames, label_list, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1338, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1322, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1303, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1080, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 30, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(30, 224, 224, 3)
```

Can anyone provide help in solving the issue and understanding the problem! Noted that I am new in video processing so I might be clumsy in explaining the issue, pardon me for that.

Comment: Not sure why you're not getting an Answer. If still needed, see if my post helps you in some way.

Answer (score 0):

> *"While running the code I am getting error in the input layer dimension incompatibility."* 
>  `ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer:` 
>  `expected shape=(None, 30, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(30, 224, 224, 3)`

This one is simple.

Every time you do a `model.add(tf.keras.layers. ... etc` command you are **adding a Layer**

One of your Layer's input is **not setup correctly** (*eg:* not enough parameters added in there).

The problem is with this line:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(inception_model, input_shape=(num_frames, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)))
```

Where your setup is:

```
# is the "found shape"
input_shape     =   (num_frames, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
```

But your `input_shape` should be setup like the "expected" shape below:

```
# is the "expected shape"
expected shape  =   (None, num_frames, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
```